# show same row value When run the program in java

Tags: java

hi my program work in back ground  and show different message from database

in specific time  the problem always show the same row

//////

**upload code **

```
public void myMethod(){ 
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
int counter = 0;

    while(true) { 
        if((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime ) == 5000){
try{
String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Quet";
String uName = "eenas";
String uPass= "2234";
con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uName, uPass);
stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * from EENAS.EENAS");

rs.next();
int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
String id =Integer.toString(id_col);
String me=rs.getString("MESSAGE");
System.out.print(me);
 rs.close();

  }
 catch(SQLException err)
 {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, err);
  }


 startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 


  continue; } 
 else{ continue; } } }
```

upload code

Comment: If your code is quickly iterating over the result set, then wouldn't the GUI be left always showing the _last_ message you processed?

Comment: `jTextArea1.setText(PMessage);` is always over-writing the value, so only the last value will show

Comment: how i can Modifying code

Comment: the code show the same value , current Cursor  from data base  move then  value appears

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

the can solve this problem by using arrayList to save all data, your program now show only that last one because they change their value every time, the solution like this,

```
public void DoConnect( ) {

 try{


    String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Quet";
    String uName = "eenas";
    String uPass= "2234";
    con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uName, uPass);
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from EENAS.EENAS");

    List<String> PMessage = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer> id_col = new ArrayList<Integer>();

   while(rs.next()){
       id_col.add(rs.getInt("ID"));
       PMessage.add(rs.getString("MESSAGE"));
       jTextArea1.setText(PMessage);
  }


   rs.close();
   stmt.close();
   con.close();

 }
 catch(SQLException err)
 {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, err);
 }


}
```

I didn't run the code on my machine but this is the logic can solve the problem.

Comment: you need to import two library,

Comment: import java.util.ArrayList and 
import java.util.List;

Comment: In this code the type of "PMessage" is array of Strings, did you define "PMessage" before?

Comment: Can you upload the hole class, and i will review it, then if i found any error will fix it and then inform you about the error

Comment: why then but red line under PMessage

Comment: i put that  jTextArea1.append(Message.toString());  but show all array i want one by one show in each run

Comment: Sorry for late, i think the red line because of the .java file, save it and rebuild the file,

Comment: you can get one by one using  jTextArea1.append(Message.get(index)); where the index is integer value for the position of the data.

Comment: for all your data you can use this code `for(int i=0; i<Message.length; i++){ jTextArea1.append(Message.get(i));}`

Comment: how i define length

Comment: length is build-in method, that come with the java language

Comment: i work in my code but the out put not good i want first element then another run show second element

Comment: if you run the code multi-time the output be the same, will change if you change the **code**

Comment: i want  my code show one element and after 2 hours show next element please hope me i work in my code but nothing

Comment: i can give you code that can change every period of time, is this will help you?

Comment: yas please put must show different  row after period time

Comment: I highly recommended for you to use **threads** but i will give the code that i said, this code run every 2 hours.

Comment: `public void myMethod(){
  
  long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // put the start time
  
  while(true)
  {
   
   if((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime ) == 7200000){ // every 2 hours run this code
    
    // print your element here
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    continue;
    
   }
   else{
    
    continue;
    
   }
  }
  
 } // end myMethod method`

Comment: you can test it by change the number 7200000 to 5000 for 5 second.

Comment: you can set counter to change element every time

Comment: under this line `long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();`

Comment: define it like this `int counter = 0`

Comment: and then after this `startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); `

Comment: make it increase by `counter++`

Comment: every time print the element of counter, start at 0 until the end

Comment: you edit my code, i did not understand it, please upload it as new post

Comment: you do not need to use this counter in your code, just delete `rs.next();` from your code, and then check it

Comment: same problem i can not show one row and then after 5 second clean and show next row

Comment: i understand what is the problem, just make the timer code inside the while code, `while(rs.next()){

   int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
  String id =Integer.toString(id_col);
             String me=rs.getString("MESSAGE");


    System.out.print(me);




  }`

Comment: in this case, the code will print the data every period of time

Comment: take this `int id_col = rs.getInt("ID"); String id =Integer.toString(id_col); String me=rs.getString("MESSAGE"); System.out.print(me);` and put it in the period of time code

Comment: i upload now is that true

Comment: in up in question

Comment: no, i mean inside the while loop, not take it out, under `while(true)`

Comment: any one can help please i will waite for any help

Comment: did you see all data when run your code without timer?

Comment: cause if you see them, i can make every element be printed after period of time

Comment: i can help, but i did not full understand your goal

Comment: thanks you help me alote my golas my data base show one column with alote of row i want my app show one row then after specific time delete that row and show new row my app work in background

Comment: let me say what i understand, you have **data** in the database, you want show the data **one by one** , but this code **print all the data** , or i'm not correct

Comment: i can't solve problem that i don't understand it, help me to understand it, so i can solve it for you